# Ajax to read and print JSON in browser - cannot read property map

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I haven't worked with jquery or ajax before, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on the issue I'm running into.

I've been working through the tutorial here `https://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/` using my own json data.

I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

I can't see how my code varies from the tutorial (other than a few variable names) so I'm unsure where I'm going wrong.  any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>tutorial 01</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="button">Load JSON</button>
    <div id="show-data"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#button').click(function () {
                var showData = $('#show-data');

                $.getJSON('json.txt', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    var items = data.items.map(function (item) {
                        return item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName;
                    });

                    showData.empty();

                    if (items.length) {
                        var content = '<li>' + items.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
                        var list = $('ul />').html(content);
                        showData.append(list);
                    }
                });
                showData.text('Loading the JSON file.');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

edit: JSON data:

```
{"employees":[ {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
            {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
            {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
         ]}
```

Comment: The problem is most likely you json file. You should post a copy of your json file, but from your code you will need an object within the json called "items".

Comment: `data.items` should be `data.employees`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to access employees property on data object

```
var items = data.employees.map(function (item) {
                            return item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName;
                        });
```

Comment: Perfect.  This was correct.  I'm simply unfamiliar with how to access the json data.  I appreciate your help! will accept answer as soon as the time allows me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors